# Pumping lemma for $a^n b^{2n}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I have this question and i am not sure and trying to solve in both way  that is through diagram and expression:

Question : Prove that $a^nb^{2n}$  is not regular.

contradiction:

```
 Assume language is regular
----->()------>()------>(o)
      x         y        z

     x y^i z

 through diagram:  abb    when y^0
                   aabb      , y^1
                   aaabbb       y=2
so given language is not regular.
```

Is it correct?? Thanks

Comment: no one? if i am wrong kindly correct me.

Comment: Your argument does not make any sense to me.  Either it is in a highly abbreviated form that will make sense to your grader, or it will be as much a puzzle to them as it is to me.  If the latter, you will probably get a zero.